# NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml with named groups url

Tags: django

Accessing to www.example.com/sitemap.xml returning following error:

```
reverse for 'netherland' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have followings url

```
url(r'^(?P<country>netherland|germany|spain)/$', FeedList.as_view()),
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

and here is my sitemaps.py

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['netherland', 'germany', 'spain']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just give a name to the URL conf such as:

```
url(r'^(?P<country>netherland|germany|spain)/$', FeedList.as_view(), name="country")
```

and then instead build the location in the sitemap to be:

```
def location(self, item):
    return reverse("country", kwargs={"country": item}
```

or something similar to your logic.